# is it posible to convert double values with different lenght to 2 digits before the dot

Tags: java, android, double

In my case i have different double values, have 9 to 5 values before the dot, e.g. 484220441.0, 46124386.0, 4912351.0 and 49063.0

these values now should look like this:
48.4220441, 46.124386, 49.12351, 49.063

Is there any method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide until it reaches the right size:

```
public double convertTwoDigits(double num) {
    While (num > 100) {
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

or more generic

```
public double convertDigits(double num, int digits) {
    int max = Math.pow(10, digits);
    While (num > max) {
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: oh my god i'm so dumb. thanks for your answer it worked :)